# problem with change of pagenumbering with twoside

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, koma-script, double-sided

I am using scrartcl with the twopage option to get a two sided document. 
The result is as desired.

If I change the pagenumbering after the first few pages (title page, list of contents, ...) from roman to arabic the pagecounter is resetted.
This is desired as well. 
however, what I don't want is that the orientation of the page (left/right) is resetted as well. How can i avoid this?

Here is a mimimal working example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\section{right page, as it should be}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext 
\newpage

\section{left page, as it should be}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext 
\newpage

\section{right page, as it should be}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext 
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{right page again. this should be a left page}
\blindtext \blindtext \blindtext 
\newpage

\end{document}
```

This question has also been asked [here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=23706&p=80642#p80642) and [there](http://www.golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=51387) where the answer was provided (see also below).

Answer (score 3):

Just put in a `\cleardoublepage` before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. Page `1` will be after a blank page. Apparently it is bad style to have page `1` on the left...